Can't attribute an int value to a variable every time I change it via spinbox and use it in the rest of my program
I'm making a program that display the location of a vehicule on a map, I use "tkintermapview" to display a map, and tkinter to display stuff on it (road it's suppose to be on, icone to show where it is and a trail to show where it went).
I want to show the historic of where it went during the last X seconds/minuts, in order to do that I ask via a spinbox a value of X seconds.
My problem is that I can't get the value in a variable ( new variable) outside of the fonction
I tried a lot of stuff, mostly declaring the variable in different ways.
It was suggested to me to use threading but idk how to use it so I'm looking for another option. Not the actual whole code just something to show where i'm strugling
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

# Créer une fenêtre principale
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TinkerMapView avec Entrée Numérique")

# Fonction pour récupérer la valeur entrée
def get_user_input():
    user_input = simpledialog.askfloat("Input", "Entrez une valeur numérique:")
    if user_input is not None:
        print(f"Valeur entrée: {user_input}")#the goal of this print is to see if the value is correct (i dont want to print anything otherwise)

# Ajouter un bouton pour obtenir l'entrée de l'utilisateur
get_input_button = tk.Button(root, text="Entrer une valeur numérique", command=get_user_input)
get_input_button.pack(pady=20)

#//////////////////////////////
#I want to use the variable here
#//////////////////////////////

# Lancer la boucle principale de Tkinter
root.mainloop()


@AndrewYim thanks for your suggestions but the print was just to see if the value in the variable was correct, I actually dont use any print in my program otherwise

You still need to put the input value somewhere that the rest of the program can access it. You could make user_input a global variable, for example.

@AndrewYim Returning the value is not useful in a callback function.

Ah, I missed that

I see two common problem in your code - all because GUis works in different way than text applications and people don't now it. (1) Button run get_user_input() inside mainloop and it can't get result from this function and assign to external variable - so you have to use global user_input inside this function to assign it to external variable - to have access to this value in other functions.

(2) GUI doesn't work like input() in text mode - Button() doesn't wait for result - it is only information what to display in window and later mainloop() will display it - so everything used before line with mainloop() (which you marked as #I want to use the variable here) is executed before you see window - and before you click button - so you can't get and use user_input in this part. If you want to do something with user_input then do it directly in function get_user_input():
